# Regex.Match for a string like sampleText(any Alphanumeric charectors)

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string as

`"AND A.BrandId IN (0,1,3,5,9,10)  AND AgeGroup IN (0-24,24-36)  AND Gender IN (0,1,2)"`

and I want to replace the `"AgeGroup IN (0-24,24-36)"` with other text, keeping the remaining part of the string as it as. How to do that?

Comment: I think you should post a few other examples. Regular expressions are all about matching what you need, despite differences in what needs to be checked. If this is what all you have, the James Didzun is right, just use replace.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to use the `String.Replace("Old String", "New String")` method for this, instead of using [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions):

## Example:

```
string oldFoo = "AND A.BrandId IN (0,1,3,5,9,10) AND AgeGroup IN (0-24,24-36) AND Gender IN (0,1,2)";
string newFoo;
newFoo = oldFoo.Replace("AgeGroup IN (0-24,24-36)", "newFooText");
```

---

More Information on the String.Replace() Method: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Comment: thanks James, Sorry I should be clear in my question. Right now only two parameters in AgeGroup In 0-214, 24-36, but in future number of parmeter will change. it may contain n of parameters say for example AgeGroup IN (0-2, 0-4, 24-56,24-36, 4-12) some thing like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that your string may change to AgeGroup IN (0-2, 0-4, 24-56,24-36, 4-12) some thing like that, you can use Regular expressions to replace this string with other string.

```
                string newString = Regex.Replace(str, @"AgeGroup\sIN\s\((\s*\d*[-]\d*,*)*\)", "Other_Text");
```

You can have look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx).